# Automatically choose Download Location, Ebook Library, PDF, Epub, Mobi on the MAC ios

Tags: macos, download, epub

I am creating a flipbook for a client, it will be flash based however the client wants an option for Mac users to which when they click on download file, thats fine as it is pdf but now they want it to automatically goe into their ebook library on their system, rather than a downloads folder Is this achievable, thinking that i might have to reformat it to be of a completely different file type? any ideas?